# Error ' [Errno 2] No such file or directory' when trying to create a new Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm following a Udemy course on learning Python and I have got to a part about learning Django. I have created a folder on my desktop and tried to start a Django project in it using CMD, however when I try to start the project I get the error:

> d:\python\python: can't open file '3.6\python.exe': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have tried finding solutions but since I've never really used CMD I have no idea what to do, please help!

I have tried searching up solutions but I've been unable to find others with the same problem. Here is what I typed in CMD:

```
C:\Users\Thomas>cd desktop

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop>cd newsite

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\newsite>django-admin startproject mysite

d:\python\python: can't open file '3.6\python.exe': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\newsite>
```

Comment: I think there is a issue with python environment setup. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows

Comment: django is not configure with python (correct me if i am wrong), you can go with pycharm for django procject for creation and maintaining it

Comment: @prashantrana, why are you talking about PyCharm? There's no need to use any specific IDE to get this working.

Comment: just to tell using ide is better than this way

Comment: @prashantrana, that's your _opinion_. Plenty of people use text editors and other IDEs to work on Python just fine. OP is taking a course and should probably stick with the tooling recommended there.